# Youtube displays white bar at top and hides player controls while in fullscreen

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, youtube

When I enter the fullscreen mode of youtube under firefox or chrome, the youtube player is aligned wrong. It shows a white bar at the top and hides the control buttons of the player while only showing the edge of the player progress bar. This happens directly after going to fullscreen and there is no change when i move my mouse. It just stays the same state.

I tried cleaning the cache in chrome first, but i think it's a problem with youtube because i have exactly the same phenomenon under firefox. Other video players (e.g. vimeo, dailymotion, reddit video) work without problems in both browsers. How can I change it to normal again?

I'm using:
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157
Firefox 66.0.5

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nurGS.jpg)

Comment: Graphics card and driver's version (if you installed)?

Comment: Graphics Card: UHD Graphics 620, driver in use is: i915 . I should mention that everything was working fine since i bought the computer 1 year ago. The problem is occurring since ~2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have uBlock Origin installed, add the following rule to cosmetic filters (*My Filters* tab)

`youtube.com##.no-scroll #page-manager:style(margin-top: 0px !important)`

I had similar problem and the above fixed it for me. Credit: [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/bqekje/youtube_on_firefox_6605_white_bar_when_playing/).

Comment: Perfect! This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Ubuntu
You might log into a account and google and see that the top white bar disappears and the display returns to normal.
There is probably a notification displayed that disturbs the normal display, maybe about cookies or so...

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem. Reloading the page and immediately entering fullscreen mode by hitting the "f" key solved this for me.

I guess, it's the search/sign-in bar that's causing the problem somehow.